# Drools Rule Engine for data based policy server

Tags: drools, dsl, policy

Here is my use case. We are trying to implement a policy sever using Drools. There could be few hundreds thousand (~200K) rules, all based data driven. Few example rules:

```
POLICY #1:  Gender = Male &&
            AGE BETWEEN 30 AND 40 &&
            BORN_STATE IN (NC,CA,PA)
===> [Outcome = Allow] 
POLICY #2:  (Gender = Male OR Gender = Female) &&
            AGE = 40 &&
            COUNTRY IN (USA,UK,BRA, IND)
===> [Outcome = Allow]
POLICY #3:  Gender = Female &&
            (AGE BETWEEN 10 AND 20 || BORN_YEAR > 1990) &&
            BORN_STATE IN (NC,CA,PA) &&
            BORN_STATE_SUPPORTIVE = TRUE
===> [Outcome = NotAllow]
```

*NOTE: I am only using 4 parameters here, but there could up to 20 parameters in any given rule*

Policy #1 and Policy #2 look simple and straight forward. However, Policy #3 is tricky. The last condition `(BORN_STATE_SUPPORTIVE = TRUE)` of Policy #3 indicates the States on the policy are "inclusive" which means, if the rule matched, the Outcome would `"NotAllow"` however, if all parameters matched but NOT `BORN_STATE` (e.g. Female, Age=15, State=NY) then the Outcome should be "Allow". It's just way for our users not to list all 47 States for this condition.

There are few other usecases:

- Find and prevent duplicate rules while rules maintanence by users
- As I mentioned, there could be thousands of these rules, so if there is a conflict (multiple conflicting rules matched), we should consider the Outcome of high priority rule.

Our users neither like Drools Guvnor nor convinced it's suitable for our need. So, we are tasked to build a custom UI to manage the rules. I am planning to come up with a DSL that our users use and generate DRL file programatically. I am not sure [Drools DSL feature](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_SOA_Platform/4.2/html/JBoss_Rules_Manual/sect-JBoss_Rules_Reference_Manual-Domain_Specific_Languages.html) would work for this.

I am familiar with Drools and DRL file. However, I am not sure some of the complexity is solvable in Drools (Ex: finding duplicate rules and Policy #3) and, if Drools would be able to handle the load. Any, reference or direction would be greatly appreciated.

**Update for `BORN_STATE_SUPPORTIVE`:**

Polic #3 Expected Behavior:

```
Input #1:   Female, Age=15, State=NC
===> [Expected Outcome = NotAllow]
Input #2:   Female, Age=25, State=NC 
===> [Expected Outcome = <age not in range, rule didn't match>] (Neither NotAllowed Nor Allowed) 
Input #3:   Female, Age=15, State=NY 
===> [Expected Outcome = Allow] (Opposite of NotAllow)
```

In short, if all other condition matched except `BORN_STATE` then the outcome must be opposite of rule. And, if any other condition didn't match, the rule must be disregarded.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a complication where there isn't one: The `BORN_STATE_SUPPORTIVE` can be eliminated by providing the operator `NOT IN`.

As for testing: you have a 20-dimensional space with discrete coordinates, which means that the number of points is at least 2^20. It won't be a problem to discover multiple or no matches at runtime, so providing a solution accepted by the boffins for this situation might be the way to go. If you need to make sure that this never occurs you'll have to validate your specs.

I advise against using priorities.

Don't create O(100000) rules. A similar case didn't work for less.

As for validation: The logic you have is based on sets of points in the 20-dimensional space S. You have two sets, `A ∪ F = S` and `A ∩ F = Φ`. Each rule defines a subset Ai ⊂ A, and you need to check that `∪Ai = A` and `Ai ∩ Aj = Φ` for all i ≠ j. Not a big problem, can be implemented in a day or two (unless you have something very weird in the 17 dimensions you haven't shown).

**Update**
There is one set of states for girls of age 15: {AL:NY,ND:WY}. So you'll have one parameter set ({15}, {AL:NY,ND:WY},...), probably other ones such as ({16:20},{AL:WY},...), ({21:99},{AL:WY},...).

If the boffins say that all (15-99) women from all states are eligible except the 15 year olds from North Carolina, you'll have to compute the set difference

```
({15:99},{AL:WY}) - ({15},{NC})
```

as a union of mutually disjoint sets (for which there is one optimum solution and many more besides). --- I have only a layman's understanding of insurance policies but I'm quite certain that a good strategy for handling these set algebraic operations will be rather self evident. After all, the "disallows" aren't the result of some random operation.

Comment: regarding `BORN_STATE_SUPPORTIVE` complications, i will come up with an example to explain it better. i think its just a question of how to represent that in DRL rule. Perhaps, i can open a separate question for that.

you will have to break the other explanation to me. Any reference where I can read about this ?

Comment: Re BORN_STATE_SUPPORTIVE: please edit your Q. --- As for the "other explanation": it's basic set theory.  Also, you might have a look at blog.athico.com/2013/02/design-patterns-in-production-systems.html, IIRC it's Section 2.4, fact classification.

Comment: I updated the Q to include some sample inputs and expected outcome for Policy #3 w.r.t `BORN_STATE_SUPPORTIVE`. I have gone thru the PDF doc, its Section 2.2 I will have to rethink about using "parameter facts". However, how do I design for grouping of conditions. e.g#1 `(A=a1 || B=b1) & C=c1`   e.g#2  `A=a1 & (B=b1 || C=c1)`  thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I don't see that the update changes anything. It is still so that for every combination of the 20 discrete attributes the result is either true or false (or, perhaps, a policy code or "nope"). --- One technical problem is to make the definition of these sets as simple as possible; the other one is how to represent them in a most concise form but without causing complications in their evaluation. A condition like `A==a1||B==b2` must be factored in two definitions with the union being implied by the processing.